# Module won't open properly / having trouble with opening file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My code is not working out for some reason. But when I don't open my file in a function it will work. So I need help opening a python file in my menu file. Here is the code:

first file:

```
from tkinter import *

def Game():

    mult = 1
    clicks = 0
    clickgame = Tk()
    clickgame.geometry("500x500")

    clickgame.title("Techno Clicker")
        
    def buttonCommand():
        global clicks
        clicks += 1*(mult)  
        clickslabel.config(text=clicks)

    def multiplyerX1():
        global clicks
        global mult
        if clicks > 99:
            clicks -= 100
            mult += 1
            clickslabel.config(text=clicks)
        else:
            lickslabel.config(text="Not Enough clicks")

             
    def multiplyerX5():
        global clicks
        global mult
        if clicks > 499: 
            clicks -= 500
            mult += 5
            clickslabel.config(text=clicks)
        else:
            clickslabel.config(text="Not Enough clicks")

    def multiplyerX10():
        global clicks
        global mult
        if clicks > 999:
            clicks -= 1000
            mult += 10
            clickslabel.config(text=clicks)
        else:
            clickslabel.config(text="Not Enough clicks")

    Background_btn = PhotoImage(file="/Users/PrivateInfo/Desktop/ClickImage-3.png")

    clickslabel = Label(clickgame, text="0 Clicks")
    clickButton = Button(clickgame, image=Background_btn, command=buttonCommand, borderwidth=0)
    clickmultX1 = Button(clickgame, text="Buy Click Multiplyer x1 (Costs 100C)", command=multiplyerX1, padx = 10, pady = 5)
    clickmultX5 = Button(clickgame, text="Buy Click Multiplyer x5 (Costs 500C)", command=multiplyerX5, padx = 10, pady = 5)
    clickmultX10 = Button(clickgame, text="Buy Click Multiplyer x10 (Costs 10000C)", command=multiplyerX10, padx = 10, pady = 5)

    clickslabel.pack()
    clickButton.pack()
    clickmultX1.pack()
    clickmultX5.pack()
    clickmultX10.pack()

    clickgame.mainloop()
```

Second File:

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import sys
import ClickingGame

mult = 1
clicks = 0

menu = Tk()

q = 0

def firegame():
    global q
    ClickingGame.Game()

TitleLabel = Label(menu, text='Welcome To Techno Play')
GameLabel = Label(menu, text='Games:')
ClickingGameButton = Button(menu, text='Clicking Game', command=firegame)
                            
TitleLabel.pack()
GameLabel.pack()
ClickingGameButton.pack()
```

Everytime I run this I get a error saying `_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1` doesn't exist". But the first file runs fine if I run it alone. I am using python idle 3.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

You have two Tk() created when your script is running, `menu = Tk()` and `clickgame = Tk()`, try chaging the one inside your first file to `Toplevel()` and delete `clickgame.mainloop()` since you change `clickgame` to a Toplevel of your main GUI.

In the first file:

```
def Game(menu):

    mult = 1
    clicks = 0
    clickgame = Toplevel(menu)
    ...
    ...
```

In the second file just make `menu` a global variable, right before `menu = Tk()`, then send this `root` when you call your function ClickingGame like this `ClickingGame.Game(menu)` and at the end of the file start the `mainloop`:

```
...
...
...
TitleLabel.pack()
GameLabel.pack()
ClickingGameButton.pack()
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks so much, You have saved me so much time. But One error occurred on the second file, code:
import os
import sys
import ClickingGame

mult = 1
clicks = 0

global menu
menu = Tk()

q = 0

def firegame():
    global q
    ClickingGame.Game()

TitleLabel = Label(menu, text='Welcome To Techno Play')
GameLabel = Label(menu, text='Games:')
ClickingGameButton = Button(menu, text='Clicking Game', command=firegame)
                            
TitleLabel.pack()
GameLabel.pack()
ClickingGameButton.pack()
menu.mainloop()

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: it says menu is not defined

Comment: Answer edited, this should work!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `clickgame = Tk()`  at the beggining of the file that contains the `mainloop()` function